# updating null data with previous captured value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table "*childdataviewdetail*" with fields "*code*", "*updateon*" and "*height*".

- "*Code*" represents the code of Child;
- "*Updateon*" is the date on which we take height of that child (we usually take it once a month);
- "*height*" is the height of child.

We are having around 10000 childs. Many times we forget to take their height so it capture null for the same.
I need a query to update null value with the latest value taken before that day.

I have written a code which works fine but it is taking too long. I need to know if there is any other possible way to do it fast.

```
select
 code,
 updateon,
 iif(height is null, 
    (select top 1 height              
     from childdataviewdetail
     where code = t1.code 
            and updateon<=t1.updateon 
            and height is not null
     order by updateon desc)
    ,height) height
from childdataviewdetail t1
order by code, updateon
```

I am getting the expected result but query is taking to long to execute. Please suggest any alternative.

Comment: So you want to replace every null with the most recent non-null value to that date?

Comment: I dont want it to be replaced in original table. I need a query to get output like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions.  However, you seem to want `lag(ignore nulls)`, which SQL Server does not support.  One method is two levels of window functions:

```
select cdvd.*,  -- whatever columns you want here
       coalesce(height,
                max(height) over (partition by code, grp)
               ) as height
from (select cdvd.*,
             count(height) over (partition by code order by updateon) as grp
      from childdataviewdetail cdvd
     ) cdvd
order by code, updateon;
```

If `height` is never decreasing, then you can use a cumulative `max()`, which is simpler:

```
select cdvd.*,  -- whatever columns you want here
       coalesce(height,
                max(height) over (partition by code order by updatedon)
               ) as height
from childdataviewdetail cdvd
```